how to increase some distance to vector3 position
When player enters outbound collider, I save his last position:
public void outboundEnter()
{
    lastOutsidePosition = player.transform.position;
}

After a few seconds if he doesn't get out, I teleport him back
public void teleportOut()
{
    player.transform.position = lastOutsidePosition;
}

The problem is that lastOutsidePosition is the same position where the collision started.
So I need to increase some values on position, to move player avoiding same start collision.
I'm trying this but no success:
lastOutsidePosition.normalized * 1.3


Sounds like you want to shift that position in some direction by some amount.  You'll need a direction vector to add that to the position.

Take the position and calculate the direction and add a bit more?

In order to change the position to something in bounds, you will need a direction vector that faces towards in bounds.
A simple direction you could use is the opposite of the players direction when they went out of bounds.  You'll want to store this direction so you can use it when teleporting back.
inBoundsDirection = -player.transform.forward;

To move the player by a specific amount, normalize the direction vector and multiply it by the distance you want to move by.
directionalMove = inBoundsDirection.normalized * distanceToMove;

This will have mixed results based on the angle the player exited.  If the angle is near parallel, then you will probably find you don't move inward enough.  If this ends up being the case, you will want to use a different direction vector.  One possible solution is the normal of "wall" you hit.  You could also expose a direction, or place the bounds so its forward faces in the inward direction.  There are many ways you can get a valid direction.
Once you have that direction multiplied by the distance, add it to your players lastOutsidePosition.
player.transform.position = lastOutsidePosition + directionalMove;


pretty detailed answer, thank you!
